# Controller ou resource controller, como determinar qual utilizar?

Tags: laravel

Estou criando uma pequena aplicação utilizando o `Laravel 5.6`, entretanto, estou com dificuldade para determinar a nomenclatura das rotas, ou melhor, para determinar se utilizo ou não `resource Controller`.

Atualmente tenho essas rotas:

```
Route::get('/alterar-senha','Painel\AlterarSenhaController@index')
     ->name('alterar-senha');
Route::post('/alterar-senha','Painel\AlterarSenhaController@alterarSenha')
     ->name('alterar-senha');
```

Seria relevante utilizar `resource Controller` para melhorarar a estética do meu arquivos de rotas?

**Observação:** *ainda terei outras rotas como alterar-email*

Pensei em:

```
Route::resource('alterar-senha', 'Painel\AlterarSenhaController')
     ->only(['edit', 'update']);
```

A rota para alterar email segui a mesma abordagem. Ao utilizar `resource` consigo ao invés de ter 4 linhas, ter somente 2 e visualmente uma estrutura mais agradável aos olhos, mas essa abordagem seria realmente valida?

[Projeto mencionado github](https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/laravel-boot/tree/develop)

Answer (score 2):

O Resource Controller é um controlador normal que implementa funções de CRUD por padrão , porém , ao definir um resource no arquivo de rotas , você cria várias "rotas" sem ter que escrever código para estas rotas. Veja o exemplo colocado na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers) . Criando uma rota resource para o controller PhotoController  :

`Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');`

Você tem as seguintes rotas.

Primeiro o método **HTTP** utilizado, seguido da **URL** que será utilizada, após temos o método na Controller que será executado e , por último, o nome da rota.

> - **GET**    /photos index   **photos.index**
> - **GET**    /photos/create  create  **photos.create**
> - **POST**   /photos store   photos.store GET    /photos/{photo} show    **photos.show**
> - **GET**    /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    **photos.edit**
> - **PUT/PATCH**  /photos/{photo} update  **photos.update**
> - **DELETE** /photos/{photo} destroy **photos.destroy**

Você poderá ver melhor utilizando o seguinte comando no prompt.

```
php artisan routes
```

Veja que você apenas simplificou , "agrupando" todos os tipos de requisições HTTP em uma definição de rota.

Se a resposta for útil , não esqueca de marcar como respondida.

> Sobre qual utilizar, depende muito de sua estrutura de projeto e de
>   como todas suas rotas serão organizadas. Você pode definir os resources que serão utilizados e também adicionar rotas específicas como **alterar-email**.